# Apache POI Word to Clean Html without styles or unnecessary tags

Tags: java, html, css, ms-word, apache-poi

I'm trying to convert Word documents to clean html. I'm using Apache POI but it creates a mess just like MS Word's own html saving method. What I want is something like https://html-cleaner.com/.
For example when I try to convert a table I dont want any width property or other stuff. Just some nice `<td>` and `<tr>` tags maybe with some `<b>`.

Anyone know how to achieve this? By the way I'm not forced to use Apache POI, if you know any other API for Java that achieve Word to clean html conversion, I am open to your advices.

Comment: For each `IBodyElement` in `document.getBodyElements()`: If it is a `BodyElementType.PARAGRAPH` then emit "<p>" + the text of the paragraph + "</p>". Else if it is a `BodyElementType.TABLE` then emit "<table>". For each row in `table.getRows()`: emit "<tr>". For each cell in `row.getTableCells()` emit "<td>". For each paragraph in `cell.getParagraphs()`: emit "<p>" + the text of the paragraph + "</p>". On end cell emit "</td>". Next cell. On end row emit "</tr>". Next row. On end table emit "</table>". Next `IBodyElement`.

Comment: Did you try with Apache Tika? That should give you simple clean HTML, powered internally by Apache POI but with custom rendering

Comment: @AxelRichter thats the worst case plan for me. I'm looking for more simple way

Comment: @Gagravarr I searched Apache Tika but couldnt find a good documentation how to do this. And for some reason, it seemed more complicated than POI to me. Also I have limited time for this task, thats why i didnt get into it. But if you have a documentation to do this, or an example I would be grateful.

Comment: Apache Tika ought to be easier! See http://tika.apache.org/1.15/examples.html#Parsing_to_XHTML for the code snippet you need. Or just for testing, grab the Tika App single runnable jar and pop your document through that in `--xhtml` mode

Comment: Thanks @Gagravarr ! I can accept this as an answer if you post this as one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Promoting a comment to an answer.... You should take a look at Apache Tika. Apache Tika is powered by Apache POI, and aims to give clean, semantically meaningful HTML, which I think is what you're after

If you follow the [Apache Tika example for parsing to XHTML](http://tika.apache.org/1.15/examples.html#Parsing_to_XHTML), you'd do something like:

```
public String parseToHTML() throws IOException, SAXException, TikaException {
  ContentHandler handler = new ToXMLContentHandler();

  AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
  Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
  try (InputStream stream = ContentHandlerExample.class.getResourceAsStream("test.doc")) {
    parser.parse(stream, handler, metadata);
    return handler.toString();
  }
}
```

In addition, for testing, you could just use the [runnable single-jar Tika App cli tool](http://tika.apache.org/download.html), pass that the `--xhtml` option along with your file and it'll give you back the simple clean XHTML on the command line

Comment: Thank you so much Gagravarr!